# AJAX avoid repeated code

Tags: ajax, jquery, symfony

I'm using Symfony2.1 with Doctrine2.1

I'd like to use AJAX for many features on my site , editing a title , rate an article , create an entity on the fly , etc.

My question is simple :

Do I need to create a JQuery function for each functionnality , like this :

```
$('#specific-functionality').bind('click', function(e){

    var element = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    // the call
    $.ajax({
      url: element.attr('href'),
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){        

        // some custom stuff : remove a loader , show some value, change some css

      }
    });
  });
```

It sounds very heavy to me, so I was wondering if there's any framework on JS side, or a specific method I can use to avoid this. I was thinking about regrouping items by type of response (html_content , boolean, integer) but maybe something already exists to handle it nicely !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$('#specific-functionality').bind('click', function(e){`, try this:

```
$(".ajax").click(function(){

    var url = $(this).attr("href") ;
    var target = $(this).attr("data-target") ;
    if (target=="undefined"){
      alert("You forgot the target");
      return false ;
    }

    $.ajax(....
```

And in html

```
<a class="ajax" href="..." data-target="#some_id">click here </a>
```

I think it is the simplest solution. If you want some link to work via ajax, just give it class "ajax" and put `data-target` to where it should output results. All custom stuff could be placed in these `data-something` properties.

Comment: Even better, thanks ! I'm looking at the vote system of StakOverflow, and it seems to be working with the same concept !

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are asking for lighter version of JQuery ajax method. There are direct get/post methods instead of using ajax.

> ```
>  $.get(element.attr('href'), {'id': '123'}, 
>     function(data) { 
>        alert(data); 
>     } 
>  );
> ```

To configure error function

```
$.get(element.attr('href'), {'id': '123'}, function(data) {alert(data);})
.error(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var msg = jQuery.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        alert(msg.Message);
});
```

Also, you can pass callback function to do any synchronous operations like

```
function LoadData(cb)
{
    $.get(element.attr('href'), { 'test': test }, cb);
}
```

And call

```
LoadData(function(data) { 
alert(data);
otherstatements; 
});
```

For progress bar, you use JQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop functions instead of manually hiding and showing it. Note, it gets fired for every JQuery AJAX operation on the page.

```
 $('#progress')
   .ajaxStart(function () {
   //disable the submit button
   $(this).show();
   })
   .ajaxStop(function () {
   //enable the button
   $(this).hide();
   });
```